# dell poweredge 1850 drac 4 reset

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac, password-reset

I am having trouble resetting the drac credentials on a dell poweredge 1850. The drac being used is a drac 4/p. I have loaded windows and tried to run racadm racresetcfg from the dell drac tools but it doesn't work. On the physical card there is a reset button but I have not found the reset procedure for a hardware reset. Some more info I can add is that during boot the machine finds the drac and you can go into the drac settings but you cannot reset the login. I have also tried to load dells open manager tools and that didn't seem to work on a 1850

Here is the results from trying to run racadm

```
ERROR: RACADM is unable to process the requested subcommand because there is no
local RAC configuration to communicate with.

Local RACADM subcommand execution requires the following:

 1. A Remote Access Controller (RAC) must be present on the managed server
 2. Appropriate managed node software must be installed and running on the
Server
```

Comment: You should include the specific commands/results of running the commands in a code block comment so that we know what you mean by "tried to run racadm racresetcfg". Did you follow the advice here? http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/177/t/19295544

Comment: yes I have. Please see above to the results of the command.

Comment: How about resetting the password from the DRAC BIOS before Windows boots?

Comment: There is no options for a factory restart when you hit ctrl d on start up.

Comment: Does the DRAC show up as an installed device in the OS you're trying to manage it from? Does your screen look like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gz60zgxqwRM#t=07m40s when you boot into the DRAC ROM? I don't have a DRAC 4/p handy, so I don't know what it is that you're looking at when you say that the option isn't there. A picture would be helpful, since I can't seem to easily find screenshots for the DRAC ROM.

Comment: Its actually a 4/I card. Here are some screen shots. http://imgur.com/Qpbkrkk http://imgur.com/3TMur4y  I have also looked over this but it has not seemed to work http://commweb-ps3.us.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/177/t/19474001

Comment: Have you been trying things from the manual? http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/dell-remote-access-cntrllr-4-v1.70/manuals

Comment: And does the device show up as installed in Windows? Are you using the right version of the DRAC management tools?

Comment: How can you tell if its installed under windows ? and I am using the right tools

Comment: Check if it shows up in the device manager? The drivers install when you install the OpenManage Server Administrator Remote Access Components when the device is installed.

Comment: It does show under device manager. So it's installed.

Comment: Are you executing the commands from an elevated command prompt? Can you try flashing the firmware?

Comment: I have been running the command from administrator. How would I go about flashing the drac?

Comment: You can usually obtain the flash utility and ROM file through Dells support website, though you may have to contact Dell support for the correct link if it's difficult to find.

Comment: I have flashed the drac but the credentials stay the same

Comment: Flashing the DRAC doesn't change the settings, but may help you execute the RACADM command

Answer (score 0):

You have to reboot and press f2.

Then, go to iDRAC settings in system setup. Then click Reset iDRAC configurations to default on all of them. Then Click Yes to confirm, and then click Back. Then Click Finish.

If you use `racadm` for DRAC 4 then it appears your command does not have the correct syntax, try:

`racadm config -g cfgUserAdmin -o cfgUserAdminPassword -i 1`

And if you have DRAC 5 (for anyone reading):

`racadm config -g cfgUserAdmin -o cfgUserAdminPassword -i 2`

After this your password should be reset to whatever is specified in the command.

`@DK 68 61 63 6b meet 2600 IRC, try every saturday night, will be there`